# TokenMismatchException with simple laravel forms

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm working with laravel 5 and I get a TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php when I try to submit a simple form. I checked the source code on the form page and the token field is being set correctly. I've looked through several similar questions here but unfortunately none of the solutions have worked. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

This is the page with the form, create.blade.php:

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
<h1>Write a new Article</h1><hr/>

{!! Form::open() !!}

    <div class="form-grop">
        {!! Form::label('title','Title:')!!}
        {!! Form::text('title',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-grop">
        {!! Form::label('body','Body:')!!}
        {!! Form::textarea('body',null,['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-grop">
        {!! Form::submit('Post Article',null,['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control'])!!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

And this is the template which it extends, app.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <style>body { padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px}</style>

</head>
<body>

    @yield('content')
    <br><br><br><br><br>-----<br>
    @yield('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

I have a post handler in my routes.php file which should be accepting the POST data from the submitted form.

```
<?php

Route::get('about','PagesController@about');
Route::get('contact','PagesController@contact');
Route::get('articles','ArticlesController@index');

Route::get('articles/create','ArticlesController@create');
Route::get('articles/{id}','ArticlesController@show');

//This should accept the POST data
Route::post('articles','ArticlesController@store');
```

And finally, this is the articles controller.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Article;
use Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        //First we import App\Articles
        //Now we want to get all articles

        $articles = Article::all();
        return view('articles.index',compact('articles'));
    }

    public function show($id) {
        //FindOrFail automatically throws an exception 'ModelNotFoundException' if the id is invalid and we get null
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        return view('articles.show',compact('article'));
    }
    public function create() {
        return view('articles.create');
    }

    //This should just return a page with the submitted data
    public function store() {
        $input = Request::all();
        return $input;
    }
}
```

Is there something I need to configure in my env file? I've tried many of the solutions others have suggested for similar problems. I'm using chrome, I've restarted the server, I've tried adding various meta tags to the file, but nothing so far has worked. I feel like something this simple should work with no problem and I must be missing something obvious.

If somebody could point me in the right direction I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Your are not pointing the form to the `store` method.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. I modifed the view to have "{!! Form::open(['url' => 'articles']) !!}", but the problem is still the same. I checked the page code and it looks correct, pointing to "http://localhost:8888/articles", which is the correct url.

Comment: I also noticed that if I shut down the server and restart it, I would sometimes get it to work the first try only. It's really strange.

Comment: Since you are not using `Form::token()` in your code, I'll assume the rendered html does contain the hidden token field.

Comment: Yes, it looks like Form::open() handles that automatically. When I look at the rendered html I do have a token tag: `<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Q7Se9vpOSo8oG26SR2K4uWrI4AfRrzqCBODumtfS">` I'm not sure what the cause of the problem could be.

Comment: Have you tried adding `post` method to form? Have you tried moving your post route to the top of routes file?

Comment: Unfortunately I have. I even created a fresh install of laravel and set up a simple resource, and I run into the same problem with any form. This makes me think the problem is something on my machine.

Comment: I am stupid. I tried it in firefox and it worked, which made me realize that it must be a chrome issue. I went into chrome, cleared the cache, and added 'localhost' as an allowed site for cookies.Everything works now. Thanks for the help!